# Share Firebase Analytics Data With Other Google Users Per App, Not Per Project

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Can you share Analytics data with another user per app within Firebase, not per project?  I have hundreds of apps under one project and do not want users to have access to all those apps, just specific ones to view the Analytics of a specific app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, all permissions in a project are for the entire project.  However, please do state your case as a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) so the Firebase team can be aware of how people are hoping to use the dashboard.